# Unable to run chololately straight after it is installed in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is my powershell script file

```
# Set up chololately
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install awscli locally
& "choco install -y awscli"
```

But it failed when I tried to run `choco` after it is installed.

[image]

How can I run something in PS after it is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change

```
& "choco install -y awscli"
```

To just

```
choco install -y awscli
```